# how store object in file in java?

Tags: java

i want to store list in file, i used the following code: as `path` is the path of file store list in it

```
public void writeToFile(String path,List<BloomFilter> s) {
   try(ObjectOutputStream write=new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path)))
   {
    write.writeObject(s);
   }
   catch(FileNotFoundException nse)
   {
       nse.printStackTrace();
   }
   catch(IOException eio)
   {
       eio.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

but it throw the following error:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.googlecode.javaewah.datastructure.BitSet
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:766)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1128)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at searchencrypted.ReadData.writeToFile(ReadData.java:247)
    at searchencrypted.GUI.jButton4ActionPerformed(GUI.java:446)
    at searchencrypted.GUI.access$300(GUI.java:38)
    at searchencrypted.GUI$4.actionPerformed(GUI.java:173)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Looks like you can't serialize that object unless you can do away with the dependency on `BitSet`.  If you can't...then there's no dice.  You'll have to create a different object which you can serialize.

Comment: Why not use `java.util.BitSet`, which *is* serializable?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that only objects that implement the `Serializable` interface can be saved to a file that way.   And this applies *transitively* to all classes in the graph of objects being serialized ... unless you take steps to deal with it.

Some classes in the standard class library *don't* implement `Serializable` and therefore *can't* be serialized.  Typically there are sound technical reasons for this.   For example, a `Thread` cannot be serialized because it is impossible to serialize the state of a thread.  And a `Socket` cannot be serialized because it is (in general) impossible to reestablish a broken socket connection.

In your case, your `BloomFilter` objects contain direct or indirect references to a 3rd-party `Bitset` class which is not serializable.   If you look at the source code (e.g. http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.googlecode.javaewah/JavaEWAH/1.0.1/com/googlecode/javaewah/datastructure/BitSet.java/) you will see that *that* `BitSet` implements `Externalizable` instead<sup>1</sup>.  So ... you *may* be able to modify your code to use the externalization mechanism at the appropriate point.

Alternatively:

- mark the field that refers to the `BitSet` as `transient` so that it doesn't get serialized, or
- replace the 3rd-party `BitSet` with `java.util.BitSet` ... which is serializable.

---

<sup>1 - This was clearly a deliberate design decision.  The javadocs call this out as an advantage of this re-implementation of the standard `BitSet` class.</sup>